# Regular Expression for any positive or negative decimal number in a range of 0 to 10

Tags: javascript, python, regex

What is the regular expression for a decimal number with a maximum precision of 2 and decimal number should be in the range of 0-10 either positive or negative?

Valid Examples:

```
10.0
-9.5
-10
5
1.5
-0.5
0.5
8.25
```

Invalid Examples:

```
12.1232
2.23332
e666.76
11
-11
```

I have tried `^(?:10(?:\.0)?|[1-9](?:\.[0-9])?|0?\.[1-9])$` which basically checks positive decimal number in a range.

Also, tried `^\-?(\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)$` which checks any decimal number.

I don't know how can I merge both regex.

Comment: I have tried '^(?:10(?:\.0)?|[1-9](?:\.[0-9])?|0?\.[1-9])$' and '^\-?(\d+\.?\d*|\d*\.?\d+)$' regex, want to merge it together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
^-?(?:\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?|10(?:\.0{1,2})?)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xra1vO/1/) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E-%3F(%3F%3A%5Cd(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C2%7D)%3F%7C10(%3F%3A%5C.0%7B1%2C2%7D)%3F)%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `-?` - an optional `-` symbol
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\d` - any digit
  - `(?:\.\d{1,2})?` -  an optional sequence of a dot and 1 or 2 digits
  - `|` - or
  - `10` - `10` string
  - `(?:\.0{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and then 1 or 2 zeros
- `)` - end of a non-capturing group
- `$` -  end of string.